# How to update element in Redis stored in sorted set?

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I use Redis as persistence of my data in sorted set. My data looks like the following:

```
{text: 'Some text1', data: [1, 2, 3]},
{test: 'Some text2', data: [1, 3]}
.
.
.
```

How to update some element in that list? Let's say I  need update

```
{test: 'Some text2', data: [1, 3]}
```

to

```
{test: 'Some text2', data: [1, 3, 7]}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only add values to sorted set, or remove them. You cannot change/update them, except their score.

You can instead save values directly as strings:

```
SET text2 "{\"test\": \"Some text2\", data: [1, 3]}"
```

And then update them by replacing the original value

```
SET text2 "{\"test\": \"Some text2\", data: [1, 3, 7]}"
```

Other option is to store the values in Hash.

**UPDATE:**

Suppose you have User objects which are persisted as json with key "users:[id]":

```
SET users:1 "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Santtu\"}"
```

Then store the keys of user objects in sorted set "users".

```
ZADD users 1 "users:1"
ZADD users 2 "users:2"
```

You can now get the users by first querying for the keys and then for each user data:

```
ZRANGE users 0 9 # returns [ "users:1", "users:2", ...]
GET "users:1"
GET "users:2"
...
```

Change the order of users in set by changing the scores:

```
ZADD users 2 "users:123"
ZADD users 1 "users:456"
```

Comment: Thank for the reply but I need to have sorted set. Because my JSON objects should stay in sorted manner.

Comment: You should have a separate sorted set containing only the ID's of the object in correct order. Then you can fetch the actual content by the object id from hash/key.

Comment: In that case, delete the old member and add a new member with the updated list. Use MULTI/EXEC or a Lua script for atomicity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to change order of documents also?

Comment: ZADD is used both for adding element in sorted set, and setting/changing the order.

Comment: @santervo I'm just interested. Can I store user object as serialized string like "{\"test\": \"Some text2\", data: [1, 3]}" in sorted list directly?

Comment: Sure. But if you want to update it, you need to know the exact string serialisation (or rank/score), remove it first, and then add new serialisation (as suggested by @ItamarHaber).

Comment: Ahh. This is not useful for me then :) Ok and the last question: can I use user object as hashes http://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes ? I think it' more handy instead serialized string. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below command in the `redis-cli`:

`zincrby <set_name> <amount_to_be_changed> <key>`

For example:

```
redis> ZADD myzset 1 "one"
(integer) 1
redis> ZADD myzset 2 "two"
(integer) 1
redis> ZINCRBY myzset 2 "one"
"3"
redis> ZRANGE myzset 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "two"
2) "2"
3) "one"
4) "3"
```